# Why doesnt CMakeLists throw warning/error(during compilation) if one of the paths in include_directories doesn't exist?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have many paths under `include_directories()`. I want see an error or a warning when it comes across the path that doesn't exist. So I can cleanup my `CMakeLists.txt`. There are multiple `CMakeLists.txt` that I want to clean up. My `include_directories` look like this:

```
include_directories(
  "inc"
  "../../../../../../a/b/c/d/e/f/inc"
  "../../../../../../a/b/c/d/l/p/inc"
  "../../../../../../a/b/c/d/l/o/inc"
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .

 )
```

The path "inc" doesn't exist in the current branch of the `CMakeLists.txt` but doesn't throw an error.

I think `CMakeLists.txt` ignores empty strings in `include_directories()`.

Comment: I imagine cmake doesn't check include paths at all and just passes them directly to the compiler. I'm not aware of any compilers that validate include paths, they all silently ignore ones that don't exist

Comment: But cmake is a build configuration tool. Being able to detect whether the build is improperly configured is hardly unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

CMake passes include directories further to the build system and does not care much about their existens.

However, you can do it yourself with some code. Function [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) puts the list into a variable [INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_dir/INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_dir:INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) which you can iterate:

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
FOREACH(dir ${dirs})
  IF(NOT EXISTS ${dir})
     message(SEND_ERROR "directory '" ${dir} "' does not exist.")
  ENDIF(NOT EXISTS ${dir})
ENDFOREACH(dir)
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3a30442886bb46b).

Comment: Yes, this works. I haven't used CMake much, thanks for the function. Now I have to find a way to call this check in a high level place where it can check on every Cmakelists in my project. Any comments on that ?

Comment: If you have structured your project hirachically with a top-most CMakeLists.txt file (the one which triggers all other CMakeLists') you probably could redefine the `include_directories` macro. I never tried it, tough...